# How can I remove reserved space from translate?

Tags: android, animation

I trying remove reserved space after finish but the space still reserve

*XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="false">

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:startOffset="2500"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-75%" />

</set>
```

Comment: what you mean by reserved space ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui When start translate animation the view move to up but when finish , his original place stay reserved but already the view in up

Comment: what you mean by stay reserved ? and what kind of view you are moving up ? and what do you want to happen ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui The original place is taken

Comment: taken by what ? i can't understand you im sorry

Comment: Can I explain to you via Arabic because you're from Morocco

Comment: yes of course go ahead

Comment: @ismailalaoui انا لدي شعار للتطبيق في منتصف الصفحة عندما يبدأ التطبيق يوجد تأثير ينقل الشعار الى الأعلى لكن مكانه في الوسط يبقى محجوز لذلك النص المربوط فيه يبقى بمكانه اسفل لأن المكان الأصلي محجوز لكن مخفي

Comment: no it's not taken but any way you want the logo to go back or the text to move up with the logo ?

Comment: يمكنني ان أعطي النص تأثير حتى ينتقل للأعلى لكن انا ابحث عن طريقة اسهل وهي أزالة مكان الشعار الأصلي بالأسفل حتى ينتقل النص للأعلى عند الشعار , اذا لا يوجد طريقة سأقوم بعمل تأثير للنص

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the animation to your `textview` as well , that way your text will follow the logo , and there will be any space between them !

Comment: no problem and by the way , there is n space to be removed , your logo is just moved from a point to another , so the text should follow :)